# NSD single record update without full reload

Tags: domain-name-system, nsd

I have a large zonefile (2 GB) that takes 15 minutes to load into nsd.

```
nsd-control reload zone
```

I would like to add a new record to the zonefile and **avoid a full zone reload**.

Is there a strategy to avoid the 15 minute reload when applying a single record update to the zonefile?

Comment: Use DNS dynamic updates instead? Also for NSD did you try the `zonec` command explicitely before reloading it?

Comment: NSD does not support Dynamic DNS Update

Answer (score 1):

I hear NSD is best used as a *secondary* server, since it supports Zone Transfer and Incremental Zone Transfer, but not Dynamic DNS (DDNS).

One possible setup is to use a hidden DDNS-capable primary, with NSD public secondaries.